# Graphene: Difference between Abstract ObjectType and Interface

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am unable to tell the difference between a `graphene.Interface` object and a `graphene.ObjectType` object with `abstract = True` meta class options.

For example:

```
import graphene

class A(graphene.Interface):
    field_y = graphene.Int()
    field_z = graphene.String()

class B(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    field_y = graphene.Int()
    field_z = graphene.String()

class ChildA(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (A,)

    field_x = graphene.Float()

class ChildB(B):
    field_x = graphene.Float()
```

When would I use one Child over the other? When would I not use one or the other?

Any help is appreciated.